# Object Has No Attribute 'Strftime' Issue

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

This is my code:

```
now = datetime.now 

print ("Today's date is, ")
print (now.strftime("%A, %D, %B, %Y"))
```

This is the issue I am getting:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'strftime'
repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1
```

I tried changing it to datetime instead of strftime but it still doesn't work. I do have the import datetime from datetime.

Comment: `datetime.now` is a function. You want to call the function and use its return value. Use `now = datetime.now()` instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but this isn't a question, and it's not exactly clear what you need help with; like, was this just a typo (forgot the parentheses) or a genuine misunderstanding (coming from some other language where referencing a function calls it)? Check out [ask]. If it was a typo, then in the future, make a [mre] to catch basic mistakes like this.

Comment: Please also start with your own research in the future. I found that question by googling `python "AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute"`

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the first comment, `now` is a function.

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print ("Today's date is, ") 
print (now.strftime("%A, %D, %B, %Y"))
```